# How comes this password verification code isn't working?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need some help with this password verification on a login form in Microsoft Access... please understand that this is only for a school project so I'm not trying to create some uber-robust solution here. ;)

The login form has a combo box for username selection which looks up records from a table of users I have called "Users" and it also has a field for entry of the user's password (which is called "Text8").

So this is the code I have:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command13_Click()

If IsNull(Me.Text8) Or Me.Text8 = "" Then
  MsgBox "You must enter a Password.", vbExclamation
    Me.Text8.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

When I switch to Form view, leave the password field blank and click the button, nothing happens...

Once I have this figured out I'm going to expand the code and take the entered username / password and make it lookup the records in the "Users" table to see if there is match - if there is, they will be allowed access.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that nothing happens because your code is not running. Check that the click event for your command button is set to `[event procedure]`

You can ensure that the code is reached by setting a break-point and stepping through your code. To do this, put the cusor on a suitable line, say the first line, and press F9. Now, when you click the command button, if the code is working at all, that is, if the sub is reached, the code window will open and you can press F8 to step through the code.

There is nothing wrong with your code, although i would always recommend using sensible names for controls, not just defaults.

Comment: It is set to [event procedure] and I tried setting a break point as early as `Private Sub Command13_Click()` but it still doesn't run... is there any more information I can give you to help answer my question?

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. Can you back-up then compact and repair? If you still have problems, you can decompile (http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/decompile.htm). If that still does not work, get back here.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Remou - I just tried "compact and repair" but to no avail. I'm going into my IT lesson in about and hour and a half so I'll see if it works on the school's computers. If it doesn't I'll post back here.

Comment: I very much doubt that the school's computer will help. Access is a file based system.

Comment: +1 All good advice, naming conventions will make the code easier to read, and absolutely right the .text on a textbox is not what you want, I can't believe how often people get that wrong.